# Google+ SDK for iOS Add Signin button programmatically

Tags: ios, google-plus

As for G+ docs here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

The sign in button can be added using a XIB or programmatically in a UIViewController.

I have a TableViewController and I'm going to add the G+ Signin button as the accessory view of a table row:

```
subtitleCell.accessoryView = self.googlePlusSignInButton;
```

where the signin button is going to be initialized as follows:

```
-(void) setGooglePlusButtons {

    self.googlePlusSignInButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];


    UIImage *backgroundButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_search_cancel.png"];

    googlePlusSignInButton_.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                               0.0f,
                                               backgroundButtonImage.size.width,
                                               backgroundButtonImage.size.height);

    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f];
    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,
                                                                 -1.0f);

    [googlePlusSignInButton_ setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"UI_BUTTONS_LOGIN", @"")
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [googlePlusSignInButton_ setBackgroundImage:backgroundButtonImage
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    // Make sure the GPPSignInButton class is linked in because references from
    // xib file doesn't count.
    [GPPSignInButton class];

    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];

    signIn.delegate = self;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail;
    signIn.actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity",
                      nil];

}
```

The button is set up at the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setGooglePlusButtons];

//...
```

The UIViewControlled has an interface for the signin delegate:

```
@interface MXMSettingsTableViewController () <GPPSignInDelegate>
@end
```

It seems that the delegate is not being called or the shared sign in button is not linked to the instance of the controller:

```
// GPPSignInDelegate

- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error:(NSError *)error {
   ///....
}
```

I assume that

```
// Make sure the GPPSignInButton class is linked in because references from
// xib file doesn't count.
[GPPSignInButton class];
```

is linking the ViewController instance button:

```
// The button that handles Google+ sign-in.
@property (retain, nonatomic) GPPSignInButton *googlePlusSignInButton;
```

but there is something wrong in this implementation I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all you should call the sign in method on a action of your `googlePlusSignInButton`

So the code should be:

```
-(void) setGooglePlusButtons {

    self.googlePlusSignInButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];


    UIImage *backgroundButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_search_cancel.png"];

    googlePlusSignInButton_.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                               0.0f,
                                               backgroundButtonImage.size.width,
                                               backgroundButtonImage.size.height);

    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f];
    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,
                                                                 -1.0f);

    [googlePlusSignInButton_ setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"UI_BUTTONS_LOGIN", @"")
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [googlePlusSignInButton_ setBackgroundImage:backgroundButtonImage
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [googlePlusSignInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(signInGoogle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

and the sign in should be this way:

```
- (void)signInGoogle {
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.delegate = self;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.clientID = kClientID;
    signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,nil];
    signIn.actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity",nil];
    [signIn authenticate];
}
```

Your code was missing the `[signIn authenticate];` call, plust you need to also pass in your clientID, which in the above snippet is a constant value (you need to declare that)

Comment: Yes of course!!! In this way I also were able to separate this view with the "controller" object that is handling the G+ account and login (where is the kClient Id integration missing here). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Strange thing. The GooglePlus app opens but no auth is done neither the application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:is being called. The clientId is correctly configured on the developer console.

Comment: Have you added the URL type? This is the step 4 in this guide: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

Comment: Yai! The bundle Id as the url type, that super strange :). Now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @loretoparisi you should accept the answer as correct if it answered your question

Comment: Done! Well Another question. When using the      [signIn trySilentAuthentication] the app seems not to fire the -      (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error:(NSError *)error delegate so as result it seems that every time G+ logout the user. In fact, the [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication is nil after calling the trySilentAuthentication. Any idea ?

Comment: Actually it doesn't log out the user, unless you do so in your code. Is the delegate set before trying the silent auth?

Comment: Yes. [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = APP_GOOGLEPLUS_APPID;
    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
Just before calling 
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] trySilentAuthentication];
the [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate]
flow works properly and calls the delegate instead.

Answer (score 0):

Despite several solutions
there was no way to make the silentAuthentication to get working

```
- (void)initialize {
    // Read Google+ deep-link data.
    [GPPDeepLink setDelegate:self];
    [GPPDeepLink readDeepLinkAfterInstall];

    // Setup Google+ share dialog.
    [GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    // Setup Google+ signin
    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = APP_GOOGLEPLUS_APPID;
    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;

    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self momentSchemaByType:MXMGooglePlusMomentListen], nil];

    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, nil]; // defined in GTLPlusConstants.h

    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] trySilentAuthentication];

    shareAfterLogin= NO;
    trackIdToShare = nil;

    if([[MXMLogger sharedLogger] isDebug]) {
        NSLog(@"MXMGooglePlusManager initialize login %d keychain %d", [self isGooglePlusLoggedin], [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].hasAuthInKeychain);
    }
}
```

Strange thing,
the keychain has the authentication in

```
2013-09-13 13:01:35.849 musiXmatch[1090:790b] MXMGooglePlusManager initialize login 0 keychain 1
```

but the account is not logged in.

As for the docs here

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in

the implementation should be correct.