# Google plus login not working in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I am using this code for Google Plus login to access my app.

```
- (IBAction)GplusAction:(id)sender {

    // Make sure the GPPSignInButton class is linked in because references from
    // xib file doesn't count.
    [GPPSignInButton class];

    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.delegate = self;

}

- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
        return;
    }

}
```

It doesn't redirect to any page. Could you please help me to resolve my problem? If there is any simple login for Google Plus in iOS, please refer the link.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611812/google-sdk-for-ios-add-signin-button-programmatically/18612440#18612440)

Comment: @Lefteris: it shows error like

[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5b4e20

Comment: set other linker flag to -ObjC

Comment: if i set other linker flags then i get below error in xcode 6.2:

FrameWorks/GooglePFrameWork/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMUIImage+Resize.o)

ld: 198 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution by using  `OAuth 2.0 protocol`.

`Reference`: http://technogerms.com/login-with-google-using-oauth-2-0-for-ios-xcode-objective-c/

`Source code`: https://github.com/emysa341/Login-with-gmail-google-g--using-oath-2.0-protocol

Answer (score -2):

Follow below link. this is easy and well described
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in
and for your code you didn't create client Id. Follow link this demonstrate how to create client id and all remaining steps.