# How to remove GPPSignInButton's default style (text, G+ image) to add your own in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, google-plus

We're using the [GGPSignInButton](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in_button) to log into GooplePlus service.
we want to have a custom look and feel for the button, but I couldn't find a way to turn off the text and image that show up with the button automatically when I tell a UIButton he is of a kind GPPSignInButton. Here's how it looks when I add my own design inside an otherwise empty button which is GPPSignInButton:

[image]

The only way I've been able to make it disappear is pretty patchy:
(First wire up the button to a IBOutlet called gPlusButton)

`[self.gPlusButton.subviews[0] removeFromSuperview];`

I also tried using my own button, and when pressed calling manually to

`[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate]`

method seems to result in an incorrect login (for example, the login token isn't saved into the key chain Google+ later uses to silently authenticate me).

Does anyone know of a better way to design my own style for the button?
BTW it appears this is supported for [web sign in buttons](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/customize).

Comment: follow this link it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611812/google-sdk-for-ios-add-signin-button-programmatically

Answer (score 5):

Just don't use the GPPSignInButton! Your idea of calling authenticate directly is correct - just make sure you are configuring the shared instance (including the delegate and so on) *before* calling authenticate.